# Sql Query for calculate difference betwen two data with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table SQL with this structure:

```
Id_registration
Id_Person
Id_Location
DataIn
DataOut
```

This is the registartion in the db:

```
Id_registration:1, Id_Person:1;Id_Location:1;DataIn:03/01/2022;DataOut:15/01/2022
Id_registration:2, Id_Person:1;Id_Location:2;DataIn:16/01/2022;DataOut:15/02/2022
Id_registration:3, Id_Person:2;Id_Location:1;DataIn:10/10/2022;DataOut:
```

I need to make a query for getting the number of the days a person stay in a Location from two data input. For example: DataIn(01/01/2002) and DataOut(31/01/2022) result expected:

```
 Id_registration:1, Id_Person:1;Id_Location:1;Days Result:12
```

```
Id_registration:2, Id_Person:1;Id_Location:2;Days Result:15
```

```
Id_registration:3, Id_Person:1;Id_Location:2;Days Result:2
```

There is a way?

Comment: That data really isn't consumable. I'm not sure if you have semi-colon delimited data or if you are trying to demonstrate something else. DDL and DML would be a *far* better method or at least a markdown table. Do you also expect 3 different data sets here for your expected results? That's what your question implies.

Comment: The db is not mine and I don't know if it's possible to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    declare  @tbl table (Id_registration int,
    Id_Person int,
    Id_Location int,
    DataIn varchar(15),
    DataOut varchar(15))
    
    insert into @tbl
    select 1,1,1,'03/01/2022','15/01/2022'
    union
    select 2,1,2,'16/01/2022','15/02/2022'
    union
    select 3,2,1,'10/10/2022','11/11/2022'
    
   Declare @dateIn varchar(15) = '01/01/2002',
   @dateOut varchar(15) = '31/01/2022'
    
   select Id_registration,Id_Person,Id_Location,
    DATEDIFF(d, (CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime,datain,103) < 
    convert(date,@dateIn,103) THEN CONVERT(datetime,@dateIn,103) 
     ELSE convert(date, DataIn,103) END),
    (CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime,@dateOut,103) <= 
    convert(date,DataIn,103) THEN CONVERT(datetime,DataOut,103)
              WHEN CONVERT(datetime,dataout,103) > 
     convert(date,@dateOut,103) THEN convert(date,@dateOut,103) 
              ELSE CONVERT(datetime,DataOut,103) END)) as 'Days 
    Result' 

    from @tbl
    where convert(date,datain, 103) >= convert(date,@dateIn,103) or 
    convert(date, dataout, 103) <=convert(date, @dateOut, 103)

    

    To calculate the days result, considered the dataIn input value (i.e. query parameter value) as the datain date if the the actual dataIn date is less and vice versa for data out
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have strange result. With the data select I have three results. The right result is with two records.